# hibernate cascade: how to get children's id after saving?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, cascade, many-to-one

I have two entities, Task and TaskItem, they have a @ManyToOne relationship, with TaskItem being the owing side:

In Task:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "task",
           cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private @Getter @Setter Set<TaskItem> taskItems = new HashSet<TaskItem>();
```

In TaskItem:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "item_task",
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "taskItem_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "task_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private @Getter @Setter Task task;
```

My test code:

```
Task t = new Task();
TaskItem item = new TaskItem();
item.setTask(t);
t.addItem(item);
taskRepo.save(t);
```

> The test code works well but I wonder how can I get the saved item, especially the generated `id` of the item? It seems I can only get the id of task this way.

I want to write a function to save a TaskItem and return the saved entity, I have thought about saving it with `taskItemRepo` directly, but when the correspondent Task is not newly created, for example :

```
Task t = taskRepo.findOne(tid);
TaskItem item = new TaskItem();
item.setTask(t);
taskItemRepo.save(item)
```

I'll get a `detached entity` error :(

Comment: You can very well use Hibernate.initialize(task.getTaskItems()) in the same transaction after calling save method to load children.

Comment: Thanx,but I think my major problem is I can't figure out which TaskItem in the collection is the newly added one.